# Silverlight Column Chart series and data based colors

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, charts, colors

How can I build a Column Chart with its chart item's color retrieved from data that is bound to or computed by the chart series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using silverlight toolkit.

You need to style your ColumnDataPoint and set the background of the border to the required color through data binding. There is a nice blog post on MSDN about this

http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/02/04/columns-of-a-different-color-customizing-the-appearance-of-silverlight-charts-with-re-templating-and-mvvm.aspx

Hope this helps